# SQL Server:Permissions on Objects

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Can we revoke all the privileges to all the objects on SQL Server database and give access to only few tables of a particular schema

Answer (score 0):

A user, by default, has no permissions apart from what the `public` `ROLE` does; so if you've not given them any permissions, you'll just need to give them the right ones.

If you mean you have create and given a `USER` lots individual permissions, then it may be quicker to `DROP` the `USER` and recreate it with the correct ones:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE USER TestUser WITHOUT LOGIN WITH SID = 0x0105000000000009030000003A1272CDF6378A479D2C1EC4E229CB56;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.TestTable1 (ID int);

CREATE TABLE dbo.TestTable2 (ID int);
GO

GRANT INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE ON dbo.TestTable1 TO TestUser;
GRANT INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE ON dbo.TestTable2 TO TestUser;
GO

EXECUTE AS USER = N'TestUser';
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable1 (ID)
VALUES(1);

INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable2 (ID)
VALUES(11);
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.TestTable1;
SELECT *
FROM dbo.TestTable2;
GO

REVERT
GO

DROP USER TestUser;
GO
CREATE USER TestUser WITHOUT LOGIN WITH SID = 0x0105000000000009030000003A1272CDF6378A479D2C1EC4E229CB56;

GRANT INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE ON dbo.TestTable2 TO TestUser;
GO

EXECUTE AS USER = N'TestUser';
GO
--Fails
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable1 (ID)
VALUES(2);
GO
--Succeeds
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable2 (ID)
VALUES(12);
GO
--Fails
SELECT *
FROM dbo.TestTable1;
GO
--Succeeds
SELECT *
FROM dbo.TestTable2;
GO

REVERT
GO

GO

--Clean up
DROP USER TestUser;
DROP TABLE dbo.TestTable1;
DROP TABLE dbo.TestTable2;
```

If this is something you find yourself doing often, sounds like you should have Roles, and should add/remove the users from the particular roles.

Answer (score 0):

> For revoke all privileges you can get script result and run this:

```
 SELECT 'REVOKE ALL ON "' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '"."' + TABLE_NAME + '" FROM "User"' 
 FROM information_schema.tables t
```

> And for grant privileges :

```
 SELECT 'GRANT SELECT ON "' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '"."' + TABLE_NAME + '" TO "User"' 
 FROM information_schema.tables t
```